# trying to handle webtable in POM using pagefactory but error is thrown

Tags: selenium, pageobjects, page-factory

**strong text**I was trying to handle webtable in POM using pagefactory but its throwing error

if i try nto paste xpath directly but otherwise its not working

```
 @FindBy (xpath = "//table[@id='userTable']/tbody/tr[")
     WebElement before_xpath;

     @FindBy (xpath = "]/td[2]")
     WebElement after_xpath;



     @FindBy (xpath = "//table[@id='userTable']/tbody/tr")
     List<WebElement> namelist;



     //Intialising PageObjects

     public users_page() {

         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);


     }


     //Actions


  public void userlist(String nm, String un, String pw, String cpw, String hub) {


        List<WebElement> row =namelist;
           int row_count = row.size();
         System.out.println("Total no of rows " +row_count);

             for(int i=1;i<row_count;i++) {


             WebElement actual_xpath = before_xpath +i +actual_xpath;
             System.out.println("Total  " +actual_xpath);

  }

  }}
```

It is throwing error on  WebElement actual_xpath = before_xpath +i +actual_xpath;.

its showing  The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) WebElement, int

so hw i can handle this

Comment: Just use String instead of WebElement variable type and assign the FindBy annotation xpath value to it. Why use FindBy for finding an element with a pretty clear wrong xpath.

Comment: I made all Strings instead of webelement but still not working

Comment: Update your question with your current code and the current error/result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebElement do not handle, Concatenation of WebElement itself. Here before_xpath, after_xpath are WebElement itself.

If you want to concate something as what you are looking for (WebElement actual_xpath = before_xpath +i +after_xpath)

There should be string datatype of before_xpath, i  and after_xpath.

So your WebElement actual_xpath, will be have correct String to locate Xpath.

Also, concatenation of String should be in correct format of Xpath.

Comment: I did like this but not working                                                                                                   FindBy (xpath = "//table[@id='userTable']/tbody/tr[")
  String before_xpath;
  
  FindBy (xpath = "]/td[2]")
  String after_xpath;
                                                                                                                  for(int i=1;i<row_count;i++) {
   
       
    String actual_xpath = "before_xpath +i +after_xpath";
    System.out.println("Total  " +actual_xpath);

Comment: I made all Strings instead of webelement but still not working

Comment: As I said, concate string should accurate for locating WebElement

Comment: can u give an example

Comment: can u give an example

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath(stringVariable01 + "[" + i + "]" + stringVariable02 )); Where string variable should be in correct xpath way e.g. "//div[@class='XXX'])"

Comment: can i write like this @FindBy(xpath = "//table[@id='userTable']/tbody/tr[")
  String before_xpath;